# Is there a decent tool for automatically cleaning the crap out of VS solution directories?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm looking for a tool to automatically clean all the .suo, .user, files... bin, obj, directories, etc out of a VS solution directory... 
One I came across was Jeff Atwood's [CleanSourcePlus](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000368.html) but it's quite old at this point, requires .NET 1.0 to be installed (I know...but it's a pain), and was written in VB :P

I basically want the same functionality (explorer shell integration would be great) but something a bit newer and designed to handle Win32 projects, not just .NET (as CleanSourcePlus is limited too)

I was thinking about re-writing CleanSourcePlus to use .NET 2.0 (at least) and in C#, but don't want to duplicate work that's already been done...

Any good tools for this out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[TrimTree and CleanSources++](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode42TreeTrimPluginsAndMEF.aspx) ?? :)